# Change a marker depending on the clicked option from a select dropdown list

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a map with two markers (a *from* point and a *to* point), with a calculation of the distance between the two points. I am trying to make a dropdown list that when an option is clicked, the second point (*to* point) is changed and so with the calculated distance.

I am stuck on thinking how to implement it and have no solutions in mind. My goal is that when either `Cebu City` or `Davao City` is selected from the dropdown, then their respective points show up on the map and the calculated distance from `Manila` (which is the point of reference) is displayed:

```js
    window.onload = function() {

    var coords = {
      manila: {name: "Manila", lat: 14.590, lon: 120.979},
      cebu:  {name: "Cebu", lat: 10.309, lon: 123.893},
      davao: {name: "Davao", lat: 7.063, lon: 125.608}
    };

    var map = L.map('mapid').setView([coords.manila.lat,coords.manila.lon], 13);

    // add layer to map:
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        'attribution': 'Map data © <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);

    L.marker([coords.manila.lat,coords.manila.lon]).addTo(map);

    function createMarker()
    {
      var markerFrom = L.circleMarker([coords.manila.lat, coords.manila.lon], { color: "#F00", radius: 10 });
      var markerTo =  L.circleMarker([coords.cebu.lat, coords.cebu.lon], { color: "#4AFF00", radius: 10 });
      var from = markerFrom.getLatLng();
      var to = markerTo.getLatLng();
      markerFrom.bindPopup(coords.manila.name + ' ' + (from).toString());
      markerTo.bindPopup(coords.cebu.name + ' ' + (to).toString());
      map.addLayer(markerTo);
      map.addLayer(markerFrom);
      getDistance(from, to);
    }

    function getDistance(from, to)
    {
     var container = document.getElementById('distance');
        container.innerHTML = (coords.manila.name + " to " + coords.cebu.name + " - " + (from.distanceTo(to)).toFixed(0)/1000) + ' km';
    }

    createMarker();
    };
```

```css
#mapid { width: 400px; height: 300px;"}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.5.1/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.5.1/leaflet.js" defer></script>

<div id="mapid"></div>
<div id="distance"></div>

<select>
<option value="manila">Manila</option>
<option value="cebu">Cebu City</option>
<option value="davao">Davao City</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep track of your markers if you want to change/delete them. So, instead of creating local variables in your createMarker function, create public variables where you can access them later.

Step 1:

```
var markerFrom;
var markerTo;    

function createMarker()
{
     markerFrom = L.circleMarker([coords.manila.lat, coords.manila.lon], { color: "#F00", radius: 10 });
     markerTo =  L.circleMarker([coords.cebu.lat, coords.cebu.lon], { color: "#4AFF00", radius: 10 });
     var from = markerFrom.getLatLng();
     var to = markerTo.getLatLng();
     markerFrom.bindPopup(coords.manila.name + ' ' + (from).toString());
     markerTo.bindPopup(coords.cebu.name + ' ' + (to).toString());
     map.addLayer(markerTo);
     map.addLayer(markerFrom);
     getDistance(from, to);
}
```

next you need to know when the value of your select changes.

Step 2:

add change listener to your select.

```
var destinationSelect = document.getElementById("cmbDestination");

destinationSelect.addEventListener("change", function() {

});
```

inside your change function you need to remove your current destination marker, add new destination marker and update your distance.

Step 3:

```
destinationSelect.addEventListener("change", function() {
    // remove marker
    map.removeLayer(markerTo);

   // get selected value of select
   markerTo = // set selected value from select

   // add new marker according to the selected value
   map.addLayer(markerTo);

   // calculate distance
   var from = markerFrom.getLatLng();
   var to = markerTo.getLatLng();
   getDistance(from);      
});
```